# OSX Python SSL handshake error

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, handshake

I've read this error in stackoverflow many times but none of the solutions in those worked for me.

OSX El Capitan 10.11.3, Python 2.7.10, OpenSSL 0.9.8zg

- pip is updated with the latest version
- openssl installed with brew
- Following piece is run as per recommended [here](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2022#issuecomment-75506581):

  ```
  env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include" pip install requests[security] urllib3
  ```

I still receive the following error message when I run following 4 lines on python:

```
>>> import requests
>>> s = requests.Session()
>>> url = "https://www.tastekid.com/api/similar?q=pulp+fiction"
>>> requests.get(url)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 67, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 53, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 447, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO', 'sslv3 alert handshake failure')],)",)
```

Could it be cryptography error? I also tried installing cryptography module with following code, with failure:

```
$ env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include" pip install cryptography
Collecting cryptography
  Using cached cryptography-1.3.1-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_10_intel.whl
Collecting setuptools>=11.3 (from cryptography)
  Using cached setuptools-20.10.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): enum34 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cryptography)
Collecting ipaddress (from cryptography)
  Using cached ipaddress-1.0.16-py27-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyasn1>=0.1.8 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cryptography)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.4.1 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from cryptography)
Collecting idna>=2.0 (from cryptography)
  Using cached idna-2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cffi>=1.4.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cryptography)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pycparser in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cffi>=1.4.1->cryptography)
Installing collected packages: setuptools, ipaddress, idna, cryptography
  Found existing installation: setuptools 1.1.6
    Uninstalling setuptools-1.1.6:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 726, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 746, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 299, in move
    copytree(src, real_dst, symlinks=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 208, in copytree
    raise Error, errors
Error: [('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py', '/var/folders/d9/75cfznt17cjc124j3stq3qc40000gn/T/pip-sbS3mg-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/d9/75cfznt17cjc124j3stq3qc40000gn/T/pip-sbS3mg-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc', '/var/folders/d9/75cfznt17cjc124j3stq3qc40000gn/T/pip-sbS3mg-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/d9/75cfznt17cjc124j3stq3qc40000gn/T/pip-sbS3mg-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py', '/var/folders/d9/75cfznt17cjc124j3stq3qc40000gn/T/pip-sbS3mg-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/d9/75cfznt17cjc124j3stq3qc40000gn/T/pip-sbS3mg-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc', '/var/folders/d9/75cfznt17cjc124j3stq3qc40000gn/T/pip-sbS3mg-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/d9/75cfznt17cjc124j3stq3qc40000gn/T/pip-sbS3mg-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib', '/var/folders/d9/75cfznt17cjc124j3stq3qc40000gn/T/pip-sbS3mg-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/d9/75cfznt17cjc124j3stq3qc40000gn/T/pip-sbS3mg-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib'")]
```

**EDIT:**

I upgraded my OpenSSL to 1.0.2 now. Still receiving the same error. Here's the cipher list with "ECDHE" (apparently the site server supports those ciphers):

```
$ openssl ciphers -v 'ECDHE'
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA       SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-NULL-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-NULL-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
```

Comment: The problem is usually SNI support, and is a known issue with OSX that has been resolved. See the issue [here](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2022) - it's too long to summarise in a comment.

Comment: You can also try passing `verify = False` as an argument in your `GET` request. This will forgo the SSL verification process and may alleviate some issues.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan: handshake error is not caused by validation problems and thus disabling validation will not help.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan - please don't offer that advice. Also see [The most dangerous code in the world: validating SSL certificates in non-browser software](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/abstracts/ssl-client-bugs.html).

Comment: @AkshatMahajan Yes, I checked that link (in fact it's in my post as well) however I've tried every solution presented in that thread and none of them worked for me. The only solution that was there and that I couldn't apply was cryptography installation, but I'm not sure if that installation would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As can be seen from the report by [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.tastekid.com&s=2400%3acb00%3a2048%3a1%3a0%3a0%3a681b%3a8a93&latest) the server only supports ECDHE ciphers. These kind of ciphers are not available in the OpenSSL version 0.9.8 which you use. Therefore no common ciphers can be found and the handshake will fail.

Comment: Do you think a different OpenSLL version would fix this?

Comment: @agondiken: yes, using a recent version like 1.0.2 or even 1.0.1 will probably fix this problem.

Comment: I just upgraded to "OpenSSL 1.0.2g" - still the same error :(

Comment: @agondiken: are you sure that your python is using the expected openssl version? Usually you would have to recompile it. Check that `python -c "import ssl; print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION"` actually shows you that python uses the new version.